# Chrome extension for Facebook loads just on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, google-chrome

I wrote an extension which should say 'Hi.' *every* time the user clicks on a page and this is the code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name" : "first-ext",
"version" : "1.0",
"manifest_version" : 2,

"permissions":[
    "tabs"
],
"content_scripts":
[
    {
        "matches" : ["https://www.facebook.com/*"],
        "js": ["jquery.js", "f.js"],
        "css": ["style.css"]
    }
]
```

}

**f.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    alert("Hi."); 
});
```

I'm using those files and if I refresh every page everything works fine **but** if I change page by clicking on every link then the script do not run on the new page.

**For example** if open the Facebook home page the extension say "Hi.";
If now I refresh it works again.
If I click on a link of a time line of a friend then the browsers opens the page but the extension don't work. It's like if the script is not executed.
If I refresh then it works again.

It's unusual because I tried the same extension on other sites and it works fine if I refresh and if I change page by clicking some link.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). It will allow you to react to changes in the DOM. It is especialy powerfull when used together with [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker).

See this [sample extension](https://github.com/fczbkk/devfest2012/tree/master/09-mutation-observer) for details on how to use it.

Comment: I also found this: `$(elem).bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){});`. Which one I should prefer?

Comment: It depends on what exactly do you need. `DOMSubtreeModified` event works in IE9+, `MutationObserver` works in IE11+. But since you are developing a Chrome extension, I guess browser compatibility is not an issue for you. I'd prefer `MutationObserver`, it provides me with much more details about what exactly changed in DOM. `DOMSubtreeModified` tends to create infinite loops, if you update the observed node on change.