# Injected script continues onto next page

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension that injects a script into a facebook to change the look. The script only runs on the home page. The problem is that if I go to a different page on facebook from the home page the script continues to run. Also if I go to the homepage from any other page on facebook the script doesn't run. I'm not sure what is going on. I think it may have to do with my manifest.json, but I don't know. Any help would be great.

My manifest.json is

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Getting started example",
  "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup/popup.html",
    "default_title": "Bamboozle"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.facebook.com/","https://www.facebook.com/?*"], 
      "js": ["facebook/facebook.js"],
      "css" : ["facebook/facebook.css"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome extension for Facebook loads just on refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840467/chrome-extension-for-facebook-loads-just-on-refresh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a modern site for you. It dynamically updates its parts and fakes URL changes.

Either live with that or add `"tabs"` permission (it will make the webstore ask for permission to access all sites on install of your extension) and track the address change in [chrome.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) listener, then change the icon in the toolbar with [chrome.browserAction.setIcon](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setIcon) providing it a normal or a grayed out icon from your extension package.

Another possible solution is [declarativeContent API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent): give it a css selector of an element that is present only on the page you want, and use `chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()` for the action as shown in the documentation. This will work if you switch from [browserAction](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction), which you are using now, to [pageAction](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction). Or try `chrome.declarativeContent.SetIcon()` - it'll be somewhat messy: [pass arguments to chrome.declarativeContent.SetIcon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28765872/3959875).