# Chrome Extension Property Only Working On Reload

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm a creating a chrome extension to give a different look to a website I visit.

I'm only making small changes, like changing the background image, background colors, etc.

I managed to successfully change the background-image and also gave it an opacity property, but the opacity doesn't always work.

It's working when I reload the page, but it goes away if I visit pages within the website. Then shows up again if I refresh that page. The rest of the properties (background color) don't seem to have this problem.

Here's the original code on the website:

```
<div class="class1">
  <img src="someotherimg.jpg" />
</div>
```

Here's the javascript I'm using:

```
bg = document.getElementsByClassName("class1")[0];
bg.id = "bg-img";
bgImg = document.getElementById("bg-img").getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
bgImg.src = "imgiwant.jpg";

bgImg.style.opacity = '0.35';
```

Also, another problem I'm facing is that whenever a page loads, for a fraction of a second it looks like how it would without the extension and then quickly turns to how I've designed it. Is there any way around this?

EDIT: Now it's more or less random when the opacity works or doesn't work, regardless of clicking a link or refreshing. 
What's surprising is that the other properties (height, top, etc) work all the time.

Using "run_at": "document_start" failed to even show any change. With "run_at": "document_end", and "run_at": "document_idle" give the same result as not using anything at all.

For a fraction of a second, the old styles are applied and then my custom styles.

Comment: Sounds like the site is using ajax'd navigation similar to youtube or github or google search. See [Chrome extension detect Google search refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39288755) for an example. As for the other problem, use [document_start](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at). For a specific answer I need to see that site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome extension for Facebook loads just on refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840467/chrome-extension-for-facebook-loads-just-on-refresh)

Comment: Not a duplicate since I've also asked a second question. As for visiting the website, that's unfortunately not possible. The website is a Xenforo powered forum in its beta stage and hence password protected.